# Drawing gravitational equipotential surfaces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential

[image]

I chose B, because the question is saying "constant potential difference," but the answer turned out to be C. I thought about it for a long time and still don't get it (I am dumb).

Could you also explain it mathematically? If we use $-GM/r$ in this case, it wouldn't show the equipotential surfaces as C (exponentially increasing distances) since the denominator is $r$, not $r^2$...no..?

Comment: The $r$ is the denominator. If it were in the numerator, then option B would have been correct. Hint: $-GM/r_{equi} = -GM/r_{surface} + nV$ You need to rearrange and isolate $r_{equi}$ on one side. The answer will be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mag(E)=dV/dr.

For constant change in potential=dV, E*dr=constant. So the larger the E, the smaller the dr. Since E is stronger closer to the mass, dr must get smaller as we move towards M. So the equipotential surfaces come closer together.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong see potential is inversely proportional to $r$ right

So, $(1/r_1)-(1/r_2)$ is potential difference (there is other constant multiplied to it of course)

Which comes out to be $(r_2)-(r_1)/r_1r_2$while in the option you chose $r_1-r_2$ part will be same for all the cases $r_1r_2$ will keep on increasing

Hence potential difference across some displacement at larger distances will be smaller, therefore to get same potential difference distance between two of such surfaces will keep on increasing

As in the case of C

Hope it helps